# Download files to be continued in background over FTP

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

How is it possible to **background downloading of files over FTP** ?

i was trying but files downloading stop, when application enters in background.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html

> The NSURLSession class supports background transfers while your app is
>   suspended. Background transfers are provided only by sessions created
>   using a background session configuration object (as returned by a call
>   to backgroundSessionConfiguration:).